# How to debug the script in logs for shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, debugging

I am having a script which i have set in the debug mode:

```
set -x
#!/bin/sh

ALLCIRCLS="/var/tmp/release/ALLCIRCLS.txt"
NONRBTIPS="/var/tmp/release/NONRBTIP.txt"
RBTIPS="/var/tmp/release/RBTIPS.txt"
NONRBTIPGNOCIP="/var/tmp/release/NONRBTIPGNOCIP.txt"
NONRBTROOTIP="/var/tmp/release/NONRBTROOTIP.txt"
LOGFILE="/var/tmp/release/log_result.log"
release="/var/tmp/deployment/*"

for IP_ADDRESS in $(cat $NONRBTIPS); do
   echo "TEST FOR ${IP_ADDRESS}" >> $LOGFILE
   scp -r /var/tmp/deployment/* test@${IP_ADDRESS}:/var/mnt/promptbase/prompts/local_cms >> $LOGFILE
   if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
      echo "Secure copy is failed " >> $LOGFILE
      exit 1
   else
      echo "Secure copy is successfull"
   fi
done
```

As it is in debug mode I am getting output as described below:

```
+ ALLCIRCLS=/var/tmp/release/ALLCIRCLS.txt
+ NONRBTIPS=/var/tmp/release/NONRBTIP.txt
+ RBTIPS=/var/tmp/release/RBTIPS.txt
+ NONRBTIPGNOCIP=/var/tmp/release/NONRBTIPGNOCIP.txt
+ NONRBTROOTIP=/var/tmp/release/NONRBTROOTIP.txt
+ LOGFILE=/var/tmp/release/log_result.log
+ release='/var/tmp/deployment/*'
++ cat /var/tmp/release/NONRBTIP.txt
+ for IP_ADDRESS in '$(cat $NONRBTIPS)'
+ echo 'TEST FOR 172.19.117.198'
+ scp -r /var/tmp/deployment/ID_MB4_W2JUL19 test@172.19.117.198:/var/mnt/promptbase/prompts/local_cms
```

I would like to keep my terminal clean and print all the debugging of the script in the log file using `$LOGFILE`?

Comment: The shebang line (`#!/bin/sh`) *must* be the first thing in the file. You should either put `set -x` after it, or use `#!/bin/sh -x`.

Comment: ok thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output any file let's say log.txt

assumption your script name is test.sh

./test.sh > log.txt